# Curve speed down using Math.PI

Tags: javascript, math

I am trying to create a countdown that starts at 100 and ends at 30.
I want the beginning of the countdown to be really fast and then slow down and stop at 30. At the moment though the "path" of the countdown is linear.

Also to make you aware, the start number and end number may change, but still require a curved time effect.

https://jsfiddle.net/ygnvav7c/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var timer;
    var count=100;
    var ms = 1;
    var step = 5;
    var counter = setTimeout(timer, ms);

        Countdown();

    function Countdown() {
        count=count - 1;
        if (count >= 30) {
                        $('#countdown-display').html(count);
                        ms = ms + step;
                        counter = setTimeout(Countdown, ms);
                }
    }
});
```

How can I use `Math.PI` to make the time "curve"?

Comment: make the `step` change relative to the `count`

Comment: What you are looking for are `easing functions`. Google it and find one that suits your needs.

Comment: What you are probably looking for is [sinusoidal easing out](http://gizma.com/easing/#sin2)

Comment: And if you do not understand what Matt Burland pointed you to, let me point you to http://www.kirupa.com/html5/animating_with_easing_functions_in_javascript.htm where tha whole thing is explained in detail, step-by-step, and with a simple but fully working example. Even I got it and that means something ;-)

Comment: `Math.PI` is just a number, like `5` or `42` are. You cannot use them to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as I appreciate the solutions of my dear collegues but the requirement was that it **stops** at the end. So the time must go to infinite or at least close enough.

Taking 10^6 as "close enough" and the tangent function as the means to reach infinity (but not to go beyond) together with a bit of simple algebra and taking the liberty to change the counting function from decreasing to increasing we get the following to play with-not to to forget the complete ignorance of teh good ol' Chicago Manual of Style by using an infamously long and winded run-on sentence, that is additionally peppered with a lot of redundant additions.

tl;dr: We need to get the `x` in `tan(x)` as close to `PI/2` as possible but not bigger to reach that goal.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Counter</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var timer;
var counter = setTimeout(timer, ms);
var ms = 1;

var count_start = 30;
var count_end = 100;
var count = count_start;

// roughly (atan(10^6) - .02) / 68
var step  = 0.0228058;
// to avoid zero
var start = 0.02;

var brk = document.createElement("br");

function Countdown() {
    var out = document.getElementById("output");
    var text;

    if (++count <  count_end) {
        start += step;
        ms =  Math.tan(start) * count;

        counter = setTimeout(Countdown, ms);
        text = count.toString() + " - "  + ms.toString();
        text = document.createTextNode(text);
        out.appendChild(text);
        out.appendChild(brk.cloneNode());
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="Countdown()">
<p id="output" > </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Reducing the value in `step` makes the curve end earlier (you kind of "zoom in"), e.g.: `step = 0.02` lets the final step last about half a second and about 85ms with `step = 0.01`.

Comment: Thanks - I needed it to count down, but I have been able to amend the code.

Comment: Oh, yes, my bad, sorry. Just in case: exchange the values of `count_start` and `count_end`, replace `(++count <  count_end)`  with `if (--count >  count_end)` and  `ms =  Math.tan(start) *  count;` with `ms =  Math.tan(start) * (count_start - count + count_end);`

Answer (score 2):

Parameterize your count variable with some number `0 <= t <= 1`. Increment this with a regular interval (say 0.01)

e.g. for a quadratic decay:

`count = count_start + (count_end - count_start) * (1 - t) ^ 2`

For a sine-curve decay:

`count = count_start + (count_end - count_start) * sin(pi * t / 2)`

For an exponential decay:

`count = count_start + (count_end - count_start) * (1 - k ^ t) / (1 - 1 / k)`

where `k > 1`